# TabBarViewController and other non TabBarViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to pass data from one of TabBarViewController child to other ViewController which is not child of TabBarViewController?
[image: Storyboard screenshot]

Now how i can pass an array from Source Table View Controller to Statements table View Screen? they have no connection.

Comment: Please put images for your storyboard hierarchy and some code in order to help

Comment: thanks for your forward step

Comment: How the Statements Table View is presented? code?

Comment: Statements Table View is using for other puspose.i just need to pass my array from SourceTVC to StatementsTVC.i use this code
   statementTVC *testVC=[[StatementsTableViewController alloc] init];
    [testVC setArray:expectedArray];
there is an array at statementTVC named array.

Comment: Then are are passing the array `expectedArray` to the other controller ... what is the problem ?

Comment: i am getting array at SourceTVC but not at statementsTVC

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array via singleton or delegate method(s) (among others).  Google both of those, and come back for more if you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I do it using NSUserDefults.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:expectedArray forKey:@"expectedArray"];

[defaults synchronize];
```

i do it when i found the expectedArray at SourceTVC.From StatementsTVC i just import SourceTVC and get the array like this way

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

expectedArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"expectedArray"];
```